# Looking for a virtualization guide, looking to virtualise SBS 2008 and Server 2008 machines

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualization

I would like to "play" around and find out more about Virtualisation, mainly for Microsoft servers and PC's.

Any good guides or blogs would be great

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/default.aspx) has several deployment guides available.